# Custom type in SelectView (cursive)

Tags: rust, rust-cursive

I have a struct called `ArticlePreview`. It contains a title and a description.
Now I want to have a `SelectView` showing these items, so the user can choose one.
When I use the normal `.add_item(label, type)` function, the SelectView only displays one line for each Item. It looks like this:

```
Article 1 title
===============
Article 2 title
===============
Article 3 title
===============
....
```

(The `===` is just a separator in-between the items)

But now I want to also show the description of the Article in the SelectView. It should end up looking like this:

```
Article 1 title
This is the description of Article 1
================
Article 2 title
.....
```

It would be best, if I could tell the SelectView somehow that it should use the ArticlePreview.title and the ArticlePreview.description when displaying